# Is atomicity preserved between std::atomic operations?

Tags: c++11, std, atomic

I have defined the following:

```
std::atomic_int m_decoding_thread_count;
```

Can it be ensured that the following will be atomic? or can I ever have the result of load() to be different than the result of ++? i.e. can two threads ever get assigned the same thread_id?

```
int thread_id = (++m_decoding_thread_count).load();
```

**Update**

As rightfully pointed out in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35579651/1832746) the code above does not compile (my bad). The alternatives I see are:

option 1:

```
++m_decoding_thread_count;
int thread_id = m_decoding_thread_count.load();
```

option 2:

```
int thread_id = m_decoding_thread_count.fetch_add(1)++;
```

I can see how option 1 is not atomic. Option 2, on the other hand, could be almost atomic except that, to my understanding of the documentation, fetch_add() will return the value **before** the add is made, therefore having to increment it a posteriori.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't make sense now, after the edit. `operator++` is a shorthand for `.fetch_add(1)`, but it returns a plain `int`. You can't call `load` on that, nor is there any point in doing so.

Comment: Thanks . I have added an update in how I see it now. I am currently placing a mutex around the code, but it seems to me that such a simple operation should be feasible to make atomic without any additional code.

Comment: You're making this a moving target. I'd recommend a bit more thinking and more testing, before posting.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but my question is still not answered. Hopefully someone else will be able to help me.